# A more elegant solution for :nth-child content replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jQuery and I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution for this:

```
$( "ul li:nth-child(1) a span" ).append( "01" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(2) a span" ).append( "02" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(3) a span" ).append( "03" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(4) a span" ).append( "04" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(5) a span" ).append( "05" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(6) a span" ).append( "06" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(7) a span" ).append( "07" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(8) a span" ).append( "08" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(9) a span" ).append( "09" );
$( "ul li:nth-child(10) a span" ).append( "10" );
```

Comment: Can't you make use of CSS counters instead of jQuery?

Comment: @ Harry - Great idea but I prefer selectable text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the append callback function, where the first argument `i` represents the current element index (starting at 0, therefore do some `i=i+1;`. I used `++i`)

```js
$("ul li a span").append(function(i) {
  return ++i>9 ? i : "0"+i;            // Print `++i` and add leading "0" if needed
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

In JS ES6 it would look like:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul li a span'), (el, i) => {
   el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ++i>9 ? i : "0"+i );
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>LI <span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to add text to the DOM, using jQuery:

```
$( "ul li a span" ).append(function(i){
  return (i+1)<10 ? '0' + (i+1) : i+1;
});
```

```js
$("ul li a span").append(function(i) {
  return (i + 1) < 10 ? '0' + (i + 1) : i + 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, with CSS, although this text is not present in the DOM and so can't be selected:

```
ul {
  counter-reset: spanCount;
}

ul li a span {
  counter-increment: spanCount;
}

ul li a span::after {
  content: counter(spanCount, decimal-leading-zero);
}
```

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: spanCount;
}
ul li a span {
  counter-increment: spanCount;
}
ul li a span::after {
  content: counter(spanCount, decimal-leading-zero);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>original span text </span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can also be done like this: `return  ("0" + i).slice(-2)`

Comment: you should reset the `spanCount` at `ul` or `body` or any parent element. otherwise it will always be `01`

Comment: Thanks for the added improvements, guys. :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A Vanilla-JS solution:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(li, i) {
   li.querySelector('a span').textContent = ('0' + (+i + 1)).slice(-2);
});
```

> [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEBLXZ)

Comment: Thank you! Always interested in vanilla alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
$('ul li a span').each(function() {
    $(this).append(((i<10)?'0':'') + i++);
});
```

```js
var i = 1;
$('ul li a span').each(function() {
    $(this).append(((i<10)?'0':'') + i++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a>foo<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```